# Find element ID by its style

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find an `a`-tag's `ID` by its style.

My element have the class `.sort`.

The element's style is programmatically added earlier in one of two get functions, and I have to find it in a third get function.

Comment: Hiya, do you have any code show man? Will be helpful, cheers

Comment: post your code you have till now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = $('a.sort[style="foo"]').attr('id');
```

Or if you don't use inline styles(which you should not...):

```
var result = $('a.sort').filter(function(){
                            return $(this).css('foo') == valueYouAreSearching;
                        }).attr('id');
```

**Note that searching by a style sounds awkward!**
Just add the element a new class, and search for it by it's new class name:

```
var result = $('a.sort.newClass').attr('id');
```

Comment: **@DownVoter** Care to comment?

Answer (score 1):

If the element is the only one with the class `.sort`

```
var theID = $(".sort")[0].id;
```

Or you can do something like this:

```
var theID = $(".sort").filter(function() {
    return $(this).css("marginLeft") == 0;
})[0].id;
```

Gives you the first element's `ID` with class `.sort` and `marginLeft` set to `0`

To ensure that this will never break even if you have no match:

```
var theID = ($(".sort").filter(function() {
    return $(this).css("marginLeft") == 0;
})[0]||{}).id;
```

Then `ID` will contain a DOM Element's `id` or `undefined`

Comment: You could simplify it with `.attr('id')` like I did. no reason for inventing the wheel again... =)

Comment: **0.00001 VS 0.00010**. I'm choosing the readable version! It's _premature optimization, the root of all evil._

Comment: ;).. just funny to test these kind of things

Comment: And by the way. When the element doesn't exist **My method is faster** check [this jsperf](http://jsperf.com/attr-id-vs-0-id/2)

Comment: Fun fact: most of the time, micro-optimizations make no perceptible difference in your code. This is exactly why "premature optimization" is a habit to be avoided.